# Reading ints from file seperated by comma into a 2D array

Tags: java

My code is supposed to read in integer values separated by commas from a file into a 2D array. I am having trouble because of the commas. **I cannot remove commas from the original text file.** Here is what is in the original text file.

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
6, 7, 8, 9, 0
6, 7, 1, 2, 5
6, 7, 8, 9, 0
5, 4, 3, 2, 1
```

Here is my attempt at doing it.

```
int[][] m = new int[5][5];
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
        m[row][col] = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

This code gives me an InputMismatchException in line 4.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume 'input' is a scanner. Update the delimiter to be either a newline or a comma, before you read anything from input:

```
input.useDelimiter("\\n|\\s*,\\s*");
```